# Before trigger capability in Clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I'm using ReplacingMergeTree engine for a table. For each row inserted,

- I'd like to Auto increment the version number before inserting a row.
- I also want to insert a row with sign column as -1 with data from last
  version.

Does Clickhouse has "Before trigger" capability instead of doing above steps from application layer? It would save unnecessary I/O and also reduce the chance of incorrect data inserted with sign column as -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No such triggers.

And it's impossible. CH can not find a previous record with the same primary key for a reasonable time.